# DingConnect Response was success but top_up not made to the recipient number

Tags: api

I am using DingConnect API to top up a number and when I send the request for the top up. I got the success response, but the number was not topped up, and also no balance was deducted from mu ding connect account. I also tried with whitelisting API and with default empty whitelist entry.

this is the request body for endpoint api/V1/SendTransfer and response I got:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to live recharge set "ValidateOnly" is `false`. "ValidatOnly" `true` for test mode. Check doc here https://www.dingconnect.com/en-US/Api/Faq